# SSRS Hiding a Group leaves one Detail Row

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I'm having an issue when I try to hide a group based off the value of a field.  My dataset contains a pre-calculated set of fields to indicate which groups can be hidden .  This is done because I need the numbers for some aggregate calculations from all the rows, but some of the rows end up in groups that are unimportant to the user.

However, when the report renders, the group is hidden but one 'detail' row from the group remains visible.  The 'show hide based on expression' is set to the field that is a boolean indicating whether or not the group should be hidden.  Even if I do the exact same thing but instead change away from the expression and just select 'Hidden' then the same artifact occurs.

Has anyone seen this and fixed it?

Comment: Is there a single cell in the row that has a visibility set to true?  That could be causing the whole row to become visible.

Comment: All cells have their 'hidden' property set to the same value: False.  From my experience the row visibility should, and until now always has, overridden the cells value.

Comment: Have you tried setting the visibility on the group level and not on row level?

Comment: Tried doing either and both.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a Stepped report as explained in the following post?

[SSRS - Is it possible to have detail rows under a parent row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826391/ssrs-is-it-possible-to-have-detail-rows-under-a-parent-row)

From that post here is a good guide on how to create one in SSRS 2008: [How to: Create a Stepped Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281376.aspx).

Add a Parent Group to your report using the Row groups option at the bottom of the screen.

This should then show two rows, with the group name spanning both.

In the group Properties set the visibility of the Details group to be the textbox that has been used to create the group. (This should default to the field name that you have used to create the parent group)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the visibility and toggle on the row, rather than the group.

Comment: Tried doing either and both.